# Python IMAP - search by headers

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, imapclient

I am using Python's [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in my mail client, and basically I am stuck trying to look up messages by their headers. Specifically, I am trying to find all messages with a given `in_reply_to` value, which is part of `ENVELOPE`.

I have tried the following, but none of them works.

```
server.select_folder(folder_name)
server.search(['ENVELOPE[IN_REPLY_TO]', 'my_target_value'])
#server.search(['ENVELOPE.IN_REPLY_TO', 'my_target_value'])
#server.search(['IN_REPLY_TO', 'my_target_value'])
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: just a guess — 'header "in-reply-to"' might do it.

Comment: @arnt, goods news is that it does not year bad-command error. But bad news is that it returns empty list

Comment: `server.search(['HEADER references "<CAOpk5DXu7-GExP80z+t403KWoF3waQPADhOJmEtqOFnSo51grA@mail.gmail.com>"'])`

Comment: IIRC one of the well-known servers is broken and just doesn't support that search. Can't remember which and I have to concentrate on something else. If even a search for "@" or "" returns the empty set, you must be using that server.